# segmentation fault in populating struct C, narrowed down to a line

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, initialization

Yay. Segmentation fault.

However, I've narrowed it done to the exact line which is causing the segmentation fault.

Here are the relevant chunks of code:
So here is a struct I've defined.

```
typedef struct {
    int placeID;
    char *city;
    char *continent;
    char *cultural;
    char *outdoors;
    int dist_from_source;
} place_t;
```

Here is my initialisation of a place_t:

```
place_t *temp_place=NULL;
```

And the line that causes the seg fault is:

```
temp_place->placeID=tmp;
```

where tmp is just an int with value 1.

I'm sure it's just some silly pointer logic that I'm momentarily blind to, but any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You dereference a null pointer ... you have to make `temp_place` point to some allocated storage before you can try to write through it

Comment: Should I malloc some space for at initialisation then?

Comment: That'd be one way, yes

Comment: haha That fixed it. But I think I may have done it again at another location because I'm seg faulting again further down the track. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory to the struct pointer first:

```
  place_t *temp_place=malloc(sizeof(struct place_t));  //allocate memory first
  temp_place->placeID=tmp;                             //assign values
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, whenever you define a pointer to a struct, you define a place in memory which can store the address of that struct.

But until you haven't allocated memory for that struct (e.g. with `malloc` or `calloc`) and assigned the address of that memory to the pointer mentioned above, you cannot use it, because it points to nothing (or rather, doesn't point to anything useful).